# Confusion about solution of the Callan-Symanzik Equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, notation, density

In the QFT textbook by Peksin and Schroeder, they apply a hydrodynamic-bacteriological analogy to derive the solution of the Callan-Simanzik equation. Yet I'm confused with the integration boundary on the first line of Eq (12.71), p.420:

$$D(t,x) = D_{i}(\bar{x}(t;x))\exp\left(\int_{0}^{t}dt'\rho(\bar{x}(t';x))\right),\tag{12.71}$$

which is the solution to

$$\left[\frac{d}{dt}-\rho(x)\right]D(t,x) = 0.$$

Why the integration range is from $0$ to $t$ instead of $t$ to $0$? Since at the bottom of the previous page (p.419), they state that the position of the fluid element at time $t = 0$ is given by $\bar{x}(t;x)$. And in Eq (12.70) they have $\bar{x}(0;x) = x$, where $x$ is the position of the fluid element at time $t$. So we have

$$\bar{x}(0;x) = x(t), \tag{12.70}$$

$$\bar{x}(t;x) = x(t=0) .$$

Therefore I think the solution should be

$$D(t,x) = D_i(x(t=0))\exp\left(\int_0^tdt'\rho(x(t'))\right)=D_{i}(\bar{x}(t;x))\exp\left(\int_{t}^{0}dt'\rho(\bar{x}(t';x))\right)$$

but the integration range is opposite to the textbook. I think maybe the problem is due to my misunderstanding of $\bar{x}$ but I can't figure it out. Can someone help me or give me some hints?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes I do. But I can't see its relation to my problem.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks for your reply. Can you point me out more?

Comment: Your supplanting x(t) for x is highly misleading. It might help you to define $x_i=\bar x (t,x)$, instead. These quantities do not depend on t, so the only t-dependence of the PDE you are solving is in the upper limit of the integral.

Comment: Hi, I have the same trouble with you, do you figure it out?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Hi professor, could you please elaborate more or give an answer on this post? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are misreading the text, which clearly summarizes Coleman's paradigm, a stroke of pedagogical genius. The text goes out of its way to eschew the absurd $x(t)$ which you stuck into your meaningless (12.70); it is not in P&S! *x* is just *x*, a position along the tube, as indicated in the figure. It is *independent of t* !

You are meant to solve (12.68) for $D(t,x)$, a function of these two independent variables. Pick a time, *t*. Pick an *x*, and try to determine $D(t,x)$. This *x*, at that time, came from further left up the tube, an initial position he merely *defines* as $\bar x (t;x)$,  ***not***   $\bar x (-t;x)$; it is a definition. You compute it from the convection equation of the *real* (12.70), (which you skipped, in favor of its initial condition in these variables). Unlike *x*, it depends on *t*, so their differentials are related. Plot $\bar x (t;x)$, on the *x,t* plane, e.g. for constant positive velocity. (Coleman/P&S are trying to spare you the [Lagrangian vs. Eulerian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field) pictures, making it all but impossible to confuse them; all but...)

So, at $t=0$, it came from where it was, namely the very same place: $\bar x (0;x)=x$, where nothing has ever happened.

All the rest is solving (12.68) starting from Lagrangian, and devolving to Eulerian coordinates in the end, when you jump off the boat onto the river-bank!
$$
dt=-d\bar x /v(\bar x),
$$
from the real (12.70), $\frac{d}{dt}\bar x (t;x)+ v(\bar x)=0$ that you skipped (look at your plot!); and $t'=(0,t) \mapsto (x,\bar x(t))$, which yields the crucial  interchange of upper with lower limits of the integral, soaking up the - sign,
$$
D(t,x)=D_i(\bar x (t;x)) ~\exp \int_0^t
\!\!dt' ~~\rho(\bar x (t';x))\\ = D_i(\bar x (t;x)) ~\exp \int_{\bar x(t)}^x\!\!dx' ~~\rho( x')/v(x'). \tag{12.71}$$

For peace of mind, verify the solution for constant *v* and constant *ρ*. Do you see the genius of it? [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/360811/66086).

Comment: Hi professor, could you please help to check with if my answer below you is correct?

Comment: Probably. I'm not sure I fully understand it, especially the point of defining *t'*... P&S use primes to contrast dummy integration variables to the limits, but you seem to be doing something different. It is true the first integration is employing the convective derivative, and the second converts to Eulerian coordinates. Your answer is closer to the spirit of gamebm's.

Answer (score 0):

Professor Cosmas Zachos' answer makes sense, which clarifies the difference between Lagrangian vs. Eulerian coordinates. I want to add more details about how to obtain the first line of Eq.$(12.71)$.

Start from Eq.$(12.68)$,
$$\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+v(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\rho(x)\right] D(t, x)=0 \tag{12.68}$$

As indicated by Eq.$(12.70)$, I think $$t=t_0, t^\prime=0,\ \overline{x}(t^\prime,x)=x;\\ t=0,t^\prime=t_0,\ \overline{x}(t^\prime,x)=\overline{x}(t_0,x).$$
so $t$ is the normal time, $t^\prime$ is the backward time. with
$$t^\prime=t_0-t $$
Since the operator
$$\frac{D}{Dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+v(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} $$
retains its form after a time reversal, i.e.
$$\frac{D}{Dt}=-\frac{D}{Dt^\prime}=-\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t^\prime}+v(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) $$
We switch the time $t$ in Eq.$(12.68)$ into backward time $t^\prime$, so
$$\left[\frac{D}{D t^\prime} {\color{red} +} \rho(\overline{x}) \right]D( \overline{x}(t^\prime,x))=0 $$
(as shown by Eq.$(12.70)$, $\frac{D}{D t^\prime}\overline{x}(t^\prime,x)=0 $, see Appendix for more details) and the integral boundary condition becomes
$$\log D(t^\prime,x)\big\vert^{t^\prime=0}_{t^\prime=t}=-\int^{t^\prime=0}_{t^\prime=t} dt^\prime \rho(x)=\int^{t^\prime=t}_{t^\prime=0} dt^\prime \rho(\overline{x}(t^\prime,x)) $$
Finally,
$$ \begin{aligned} D(t^\prime=0,x)=D(t,x)&=D(t^\prime=t,x)\exp\left(\int^{t^\prime=t}_{t^\prime=0} dt^\prime \rho( \overline{x}(t^\prime,x)) \right)\\
&=D(t=0,x)\exp\left(\int^{t^\prime=t}_{t^\prime=0} dt^\prime \rho( \overline{x}(t^\prime,x)) \right)\\ \end{aligned} \tag{12.71}$$

---

Appendix:

The answer by gamebm in this [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/212015/peskin-schroeder-and-the-general-solution-to-callan-symanzik-equation/360811#360811) is very helpful! Since
$$\frac{\partial \overline{x}(t^\prime,x)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \overline{x}(t^\prime,x)}{\partial t^\prime}\frac{t^\prime}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial \overline{x}(t^\prime,x)}{\partial t^\prime} \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}=\frac{v(\overline{x})}{v(x)}  $$
so that
$$\frac{D}{D t^\prime}\overline{x}(t^\prime,x)=\frac{\partial \overline{x}(t^\prime,x)}{\partial t^\prime}+v(x)\frac{\partial \overline{x}(t^\prime,x)}{\partial x}=0 $$

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I took a look at your answer but have some similar doubts as Prof. Zachos. Besides, I think I got your argument on time-reversal symmetry: if we flip the sign of time, then $x(-t)$ should be a solution of the equation where one replaces $\rho\to -\rho$. But the negative sign in $x(-t)$ will also affect the definition of $\bar{x}(t,x)\to \bar{x}(-t,x)\equiv x(t,\bar{x})$ where the latter is obtained by solving$\bar{x}(t,x)$ for $x$.

Comment: If possible, try to revise your answer and be more explicit about the different definitions (you defined $t$ and $t'$ twice by switching their values, and then you did not evaluate their difference, on top of the fact that the system is not necessarily translational invariant, which adds to my confusion) and your aim so that it would be easy for others to get your point. Also, since the "original" argument (which is probably what the textbook implies) does not require the time reverse symmetry (though it is there), therefore, I have some further reluctance to follow your reasoning.